# TypeError in class definition

Tags: python

I'm writing a class like this (simplified) to represent probability distributions.
What I want is to initialize the object Distribution with only its type and the parameters, and that it has some functions assigned according to its type.

```
functions = {'exp':{
                 'parameters': ['l'],
                 'pdf': lambda x,p: exp(x/p[0])*p[0],
                 'cdf': lambda x,p: 1-exp(x/p[0]) },
             'uniform':{
                 'parameters': ['x1','x2'],
                 'pdf': lambda x,p: 1/(p[1]-p[0]),
                 'cdf': lambda x,p: (x-p[0])/(p[1]-p[0]) }
            }
class Distribution:
    def __init__(self,dist_type,**parameters):
        self.dist_type = dist_type
        self.parameters = parameters
        self.p = [ self.parameters[z] for z in functions[dist_type]['parameters'] ]

        for key,val in functions[dist_type].items():
            if key == 'parameters':
                pass
            else
                setattr(self, key, lambda x:val(x,self.p))


dist = Distribution('exp',l=3.5)
```

Now, when I run type(dist.pdf) I get that is a lambda function, but when I run the function, say dist.pdf(4.0) a TypeError: 'list' object is not a callable.

On a side note, how is the style/complexity of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are being bitten by a scoping issue in Python. In this line:

```
setattr(self, key, lambda x:val(x,self.p))
```

`val` is just a name which is looked up when the `lambda` is eventually *called*, not the object it refers to when the `lambda` is defined. One workaround is to add a second argument with a default value that *is* bound at the time of definition:

```
for key,val in functions[dist_type].items():
    if key == 'parameters':
        pass
    else:
        setattr(self, key, lambda x,val=val: val(x,self.p))
```

---

I don't know that I would try to embed subclass definitions in a dictionary like you are attempting. There are several techniques available (class factories, metaclasses) which could generate an appropriate class with something like

```
exp_dist = make_distribution('exp')
d = exp_dist(l=3.5)
d.pdf(4.0)
```

The complexity of such a solution depends on your use case, and why you've chosen to structure the `functions` dictionary the way you have. For instance, the named parameters aren't necessary for the `pdf` and `cdf` functions, but might be useful for introspection. Also, can you assume that any distribution created has exactly two methods, `pdf` and `cdf`, or could the instance have addition methods as well?

Comment: thanks, I'll check these techniques you mention. I just wanted to have a class whose functions depend on a set of parameters, the thing got more complex because the parameters I need depend on 'dist_type', that's why I was using a dictionary..

Answer (score 2):

You're the victim of a closure. Here is a possible fix:

```
    for key,val in functions[dist_type].items():
        if key == 'parameters':
            pass
        else:
            def f(x, dist=val):
                return dist(x, self.p)
            setattr(self, key, f)
```

By accident, the last value of `val` during this iteration was the `"parameters"` element of your `functions` dict, which happens to be a `list`. Because `val` was captured by the lambda, later when you call it, it attempts to call `['l'](4.5, 3.5)` - `['l']` being the value of the `"parameters"` item.

This can be demonstrated with this snippet:

```
class Distribution:
    def __init__(self,dist_type,**parameters):
        self.dist_type = dist_type
        self.parameters = parameters
        self.p = [self.parameters[z] for z in functions[dist_type]['parameters']]

        for key,val in functions[dist_type].items():
            if key == 'parameters':
                pass
            else:
                setattr(self, key, lambda x: val)


dist = Distribution('exp',l=3.5)

print dist.pdf(4.0)
```

Outputs:

> ['l']

The reason the trick with argument's default value works is that it's being evaluated at the time of function's definition, not when it's being called.

Answer (score -3):

When I try to run dist.pdf(), I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dist-pdf", line 30, in <module>
    dist.pdf()
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

The code style looks reasonable, although I hesitate a bit to setattr so much into self.  Also, your variable names could be a little more descriptive, but maybe that's because you're doing math, and often math uses poor variable names :)